# How to set the correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path

I need to save the pdfs in this format. *pdf-JobName--date/time. It was saving correctly when I was saving it on my localhost. I am wanting to upload it to server and needed to change the path to the directory. It is saving in the right folder but it is missing the extension. no errors are thrown

```
 var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("f").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
            var filename = string.Format(job.JobName, dt);
            string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/JobSetupPdfs/"), Path.GetFileName(filename));
            document.Save(path);

            // ...and start a viewer.
            Process.Start(path);
```

this is how it works correctly saving to localhost

```
  var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("f").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
 var filename = string.Format(@"C:\Development\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\{0}-- {1}.pdf", job.JobName, dt);


            document.Save(filename);

            // ...and start a viewer.
            Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: actually it does work, however it is not saving in the correct format. It is not saving with the .pdf--datetime

Comment: Please provide a clear problem statement with all relevant information: errors received, etc. There's many varied reasons such a thing might not work. Does the folder exists? Does it have the right permissions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a format string in your second example:

```
var filename = string.Format(job.JobName, dt);
```

That line of code says to format `job.JobName` with the value of `dt`, but `job.JobName` has no replacement to hold the value of `dt`. It seems you removed the format string of the first example thinking that the whole thing was for local only. Most likely you need something like:

```
var filename = string.Format("{0}--{1}.pdf", job.JobName, dt)
```